# Find matches between 2 files

Tags: regex, file, awk, matching

I'm trying to output matching lines in 2 files using AWK. I made it easier by making 2 files with just one column, they're phone numbers. I found many people asking the same question and getting the answer to use :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a{print $1}' file1 file2
```

The problem I encountered was that it simply doesn't want to work. The first file is small (~5MB) and the second file is considerably larger (~250MB).
I have some general knowledge of AWK and know that the above script should work, yet I'm unable to figure out why it's not.

Is there any other way I can achieve the same result?
GREP is a nice tool, but it clogs up the RAM and dies within seconds due to the file size.
I did run some spot checks to find out whether there are matches, and when I did a grep of random numbers from the smaller file and grep'd them through the big one and I did find matches, so I'm sure that there are.

Any help is appreciated!

[edit as requested by @Jaypal]

Sample code from both files :
File1:

```
01234567895
01234577896
01234556894
```

File2:

```
01234642784
02613467246
01234567895
```

Output:

```
01234567895
```

What I get:

```
xxx@xxx:~$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a{print $1}' file1 file2
xxx@xxx:~$
```

Comment: In what way does the awk script not work? Do you get an error?  Does it hang?  Does it produce the wrong output?

Comment: The script doesn't output any errors, just thinks for a while, and exits. Tried both into sdtout and into an outfile, both return empty.

Comment: @VaughnCato Also, thanks for editing it for me ^^

Comment: @Qzak I don't see any reason why it would fail at 250 MB size. I have parsed files in GBs with no issues. Please tell us the error you are getting? Show some sample text from both files and your desired output.

Comment: @Qzak Thanks for updating the question. The only thing I can think of is you may have hidden spaces or windows like formatting. Can you also put the output by doing `cat -vet` on both filenames?

Comment: What version of awk are you using?

Comment: @VaughnCato GNU Awk 4.0.1

Comment: @jaypal cat -vet outputs the phone numbers in the small file with a '$' at the end, the big file outputs them with a '^M$' at the end.

Comment: Then you should do `dos2unix` to the files.

Comment: Haha, @fedorqui That is the answer! DINGDINGDING! Thanks very much, is there a way to mark this as the answer? or just edit your current one and add the dos2unix? Either way, Great job!

Comment: @Qzak Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: @jaypal your input is appreciated as well, thanks a lot for the push in the right direction ^^

Comment: If the files are sorted, `comm file1 file2` should help, otherwise, in `bash` you can `comm <(sort -n file1) <(sort -n file2)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

The problem happens to be with the kind of file you were using. Apparently it came from a DOS system and had many `\r` around. To solve it, do "sanitize" them with:

```
dos2unix
```

---

### Former answer

Your `awk` is pretty fine. However, you can also compare files with `grep -f`:

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

This will look for lines in `file1` that are also in `file2`.

You can add options to make a better matching:

```
grep -wFf file1 file2
```

- `-w` matches words
- `-F` matches fixed strings (no regex).

#### Examples

```
$ cat a
hello
how are
you
I am fine areare
$ cat b
hel
are

$ grep -f b a
hello
how are
I am fine areare

$ grep -wf b a
how are
```

Comment: The files are too big to run through grep, the tool dies before it gets the results. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: What if you split the file in pieces?

Comment: I have many of those small 5MB files, splitting the big one would increase the amount of work significantly.

Comment: What if you split the 250MB in two or three? There shouldn't be problems on grepping.

Comment: That is an option, though I was hoping that the problem with AWK would be resolved as I feel that I will want to use AWK for different things in the future.

Comment: OK. Well, my suggestions applies for both `grep` and `awk` approaches. It is strange that you do not get any output and exits within few seconds. I would dig into that, because your `awk` command is fine.